# No binary rubies available for: osx

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, macos-mojave

I try to install a ruby version via rvm but the installation fails with the following error

```
> ruby-2.4.5 - #making binaries executable.
> Error running '__rvm_set_executable /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/bin/*',
  please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/1541865833_ruby-2.4.5/chmod.bin.log
```

before it I read a note that

```
> No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.4.5.
```

I googled a lot to find a solution and many posts mentioned that it can be problem with Xcode, but I installed it and the problem is still present

I have MacOS Mojave, version 10.14.1

Log below

```
current path: /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.5
GEM_HOME=/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python/site-packages:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global
command(2): __rvm_set_executable /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/bin/*
++ for __file in '"$@"'
++ [[ -x /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/bin/* ]]
++ chmod +x '/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/bin/*'
chmod: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/bin/*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is the rvm version you have? I've recently installed ruby 2.5.3 from binaries using the latest rvm...